# Visual Studio Database Project References

Tags: sql-server, version-control, visual-studio-2019, database-project, schema-compare

I’m really confused with how to use database projects in Visual Studio (2019).

I’ve created a new project and imported my database into it. I then can happily edit the SQL and commit it into source control, however, when I try to deploy the items to the server it fails due to unresolved references.

To get around this I have added in a reference to my database and changed the SQL to use the reference like so:

`SELECT * FROM [$(DataBase)].dbo.TableName`

The project then builds and I can deploy the SQL to my server with:

Tools> SQL server > New Schema Comparison

However what do I then do if I want to edit that SQL and make any changes?

Currently I’m using the “open by default” feature to open the SQL into SSMS (as the editor in visual studio does not appear to have the ability to execute the sql), and then find and replacing the [$(Database)] text with my database name, then making and testing my changes and then cut and pasting it back into Visual Studio and find and replacing the [$(database)] text back in.

I can’t help but think that I'm surely missing something here‽ I find it hard to believe that the workflow is this longwinded.